# Converting weak convergence to convergence in probability

Tags: probability-theory

We know that if $X_n\to X$ in distribution, it need not be the case that $X_n\to X$ in probability, the classic example being the central limit theorem.

Suppose we are given a sequence of distributions that converge weakly, say $\mu_n\to \mu.$ Can we always create a joint distribution on a sequence of random variables $X_1,X_2,\ldots,$ such that $X_n\sim\mu_n$ and $X_n\to X$ in probability (which then implies $X\sim\mu$)?

Comment: You can something stronger (almost sure convergence) by Skorokhord Represtation

Comment: Thanks Saty. That does it. :) I found a blog proof here: https://eventuallyalmosteverywhere.wordpress.com/2014/10/13/skorohod-representation-theorem/